# docker makes port of container open to public

Tags: docker, containers, port, centos7, firewalld

I have on centos7 docker container with nginx.

Port 80 is available from outside despite on that this port NOT opened in firewalld.
here rules for public zone:

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno3
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  sourceports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

but there is a automatic rule for this port in chain DOCKER:

```
# iptables -L DOCKER
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http
```

how to CLOSE this port from outside?
I've ran the command but it not helped:

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=80/tcp --permanent
Warning: NOT_ENABLED: 80:tcp
success
```

I've read docs - https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/
but still don't get it..
Actually I need open this port 80 only for my specified network 1.2.3.4/24.

Comment: This ip `172.17.0.2` belongs to a software defined network from docker, that is not directly accessible from outside the host. Have you tried to access it from outside?

Comment: how it is possible access this network (172.17.0.0/24) from outside?? I can access only external_ip_docker_host:80 and son't understand how to close this access.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit overdue, but:

you probably are mapping with something like `3000:3000`. This is very much the equivalent of `0.0.0.0:3000:3000`.

What you want is to map only to your localhost. You can achieve  this by listening to a specific IP address, such as `127.0.0.1` (localhost).

Change your configuration to `127.0.0.1:[host_port]:[container_port]`.

Comment: This is not working... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Docker sets iptables rules per default. See [Docker's Understand container communication](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communicating-to-the-outside-world) for more information. You can also disable this in the Docker daemon with `--iptables=false`.

Alternativly with docker-compose file version 2+ you could use the `expose` keyword instead of `ports` to open this port only within the Docker network in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

That said, you should probably disable iptables if you want to use firewalld.

Comment: I have disabled iptables as far I know:

    # systemctl status iptables
    Unit iptables.service could not be found.

Comment: if I use option --iptables=false I get the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792765/docker-internet-connectivity-with-iptables-false

I can't get access to Internet FROM my docker container

Comment: If you set `--iptables=false` you would have to manually configure forwarding to and from your Docker container.